# TensorFlow Lite Architecture kernels

Tags: kernel, tensorflow-lite

My name is JINWOO. I study about tensorflow lite.
Could I ask about TensorFlow Lite Architecture.

First, see the 'https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/tflite/'.
It explains about Kernels.
What is 'Kernels'?

1. kernel methods (from SVM)
2. kernel implementations (like Const, Var, MatMul, Conv2D, ReLU)
   -> https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/architecture

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'What is a kernel method' search takes simply to wiki which everyone can read. Try to do enough self home work before asking it here. Provide more input to get more helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

"kernel" has different meanings for the two cases.

1. kernel methods: the meaning of kernel is derived from kernel function, as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method).
2. kernel implementations: the meaning of kernel is derived from [compute kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compute_kernel). A "kernel" is the implementation of an op (ex: conv) that can target particular hardware acceleration (GPU, Arm Neon).